# C# converting to send a message from client to server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, client, communication

i am currently trying to realize a communication between server and client.
I am already able to connect and disconnect to the server.
No i try to send actual data. Here is my problem ...
I created a method (in unity-c#) to send a message:

```
    public void SendServerMessage(message mes)
{
    if (connectedToServer)
    {
        try
        {
            // convert message into a byte array, wrap the message with framing
            Debug.Log("1");
            byte[] messageObject = ConversionTools.convertObjectToBytes(mes);
            Debug.Log("2");
            byte[] readyMessage = ConversionTools.wrapMessage(messageObject);
            Debug.Log("3");

            // send completed message
            cSock.Send(readyMessage);
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.Log("There was an error sending server message " + mes.messageText);
        }
    }
}
```

--> I get the Debug.Log("1"); output but then i get the error message from the catch-block.
Here is the function :

```
        public static byte[] convertObjectToBytes(object o)
    {
        //used when sending our custom classes
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        binForm.Serialize(memStream, o);
        return memStream.ToArray();
    }
```

message is a class i created that looks like this:

```
    [Serializable]
public class message
{
    //used to communicate between Server and Client
    public string messageText;
    private List<scObject> scObjects = new List<scObject>();
    public int messageID;
    [...]
```

It is able to manipulate the object by adding strings etc.

I really hope you guys can help me with this issue :(
I actually created this with the help of a tutorial and in the tutorial from 2012 the code works. I googled and tried a lot but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Wright "catch (Exception ex)". What is at ex.Message?

Comment: What he said ^^ ...  Most likely you are trying to serialize a property that doesn't like to be serialized. Remember that most c# types are variable in size, so cannot be handled the same way as in a C++ or Pascal way. Most of the times it's easier to just write the conversion yourself, or look to add more serializing attributes (could be you are using the wrong attributes, happend to me)

Comment: Your try / catch mechanism is indiscriminate in what kind of exceptions it reacts to thus hiding the problem from you.  Either add more specific catches or try stepping through your code line by line in the debugger, or do both.